# Angular Search query not working with Advanced Search

Tags: angularjs, filter, angular-filters

I am trying to create advance search using angular query on different available parameters of the book objects.

The html is :

```
<div class="row row-height" ng-app='bookApp'>
    <div class="col-sm-12 login-col" style="margin-top: 2%;" ng-controller="BookSearchController">

        <div class=" row event-header" style="margin-bottom:12px;">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label style="font-size:25px;" class="control-label">Book Search</label>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="input-group" id="adv-search">
                <input type="text" ng-model="query[queryBy]" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for Books" />
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="filter">Filter by</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="queryBy">
                                        <option value="$" selected>All Books</option>
                                        <option value="title">Title</option>
                                        <option value="subject">Subject</option>
                                        <option value="authors">Authors</option>
                                        <option value="keywords">Keywords</option>
                                    </select>
                                  </div>


                                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


                 <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Subject</th>
                        <th>Authors</th>
                        <th>Edition</th>
                        <th>Available</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="">

                    <tr ng-repeat="book in books | filter:query track by $index">
                        <td>
                            <h4><span class="">{{$index + 1}}</span></h4>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h4><span class="">{{book.title}}</span></h4>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h4><span class="">{{book.subject}}</span></h4>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h4 ng-repeat="a in book.authors">
                            <span > {{a.name}}</span>
                           </h4>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h4><span class="">{{book.edition}}</span></h4>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h4><span class="">

                            <span ng-show="book.availability">YES</span>
                            <span ng-show="!book.availability">NO</span>

                            </span></h4>
                        </td>


                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, I wanted to build query with search box 'query' and the dropdown select valued 'queryBy'.

List of books in the table contains book object in following pattern:

```
[
    {
        "id": 47,
        "title": "Finance Management",
        "subject": "Finance",
        "ISBN": "4099",
        "publisher": {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Kummanar123",
            "publication_year": 2014,
            "publication_place": "Kath"
        },
        "authors": [
            {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "Samir pathak"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Suman sharma"
            }
        ],
        "edition": "2",
        "availability": true,
        "keywords": [
            {
                "text": "tax"
            },
            {
                "text": "finance"
            }
        ],
        "number_of_pages": 1111,
        "barcode": "2063"


     },
.
..
..

]
```

The searching works well with 'Title' and 'Subject' of the book. But, not working with 'authors', 'keywords'.
How to make search within inner objects of the book variable?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

try removing `[]` from your `ng-model` -

```
<input type="text" ng-model="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for Books" />
```

Defined it in your `controller` -

```
$scope.query;
```

Finally change your `filter` to

```
<tr ng-repeat="book in books | filter:query ">
```

Comment: Thanks @Itsik Mauyhas . Actually, the advanced filter html is not needed when using the controller. Thanks a lot.